# Show more button on Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am trying to set up a show more button to start the infinite scroll. Once the button is clicked it should infinite scroll until the end.

```
function infiniteScroll() {

    var postHolder = document.getElementById('postHolder');
    var articleCount = postHolder.getElementsByTagName('article').length + 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/handlers/InfiniteScroll.ashx?page=" + articleCount + "",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "") {
                $('.posts-holder .article:last').after(data);
            }
        }
    });
 };

$("#showMore").click(function () {
     infiniteScroll();
     $(window).scroll(function () {
         var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
         var scrolltrigger = 0.95;

         if (((wintop / (docheight - winheight)) > scrolltrigger) && test == 1) {
             infiniteScroll();
         }
     });
    $('#showMore').hide();
 });
```

But for some reason with this code the ajax success function gets called twice and the results get appended twice. Is there something i'm doing wrong or is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: Is `#showMore` an anchor tag? does clicking it cause the window to scroll to top, thus causing a window scroll event and executing `infiniteScroll()`?

Comment: Its just a input tag. Thanks

Comment: <input type="button" id="showMore" class="show-more-btn" value="Show more results" />

Comment: If the page is scrolled all the way to the bottom and you hide the `#showMore` button, the scroll event will happen. Hide the button before you bind the scroll event.

Comment: I tried that with not luck. It seems that the handler only gets called once but the success function gets called twice.

Comment: Right, but the handler shouldn't be getting called at all, until you scroll. That's why it's happening twice. Once when you manually run infiniteScroll, and again when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was the var scrolltrigger = 0.95; Something about the height was causing it to run twice.